# Estoy intentando importar una tabla a una base de datos de un archivo excel *.ODS desde phpmyadmin con Xampp pero me apareces este error

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Estoy importando un archivo de excel desde phpmyadmin  escojo el archivo ods:

- Conjunto de caracteres del archivo: Utf8
- formato : openDocument SpreadSheet
- Opciones específicas al formato: : La primer línea del archivo contiene los nombres de columna de la tabla (si no está activado la primera línea será parte de los datos)

pero me aparece este error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to PhpMyAdmin\Import::detectType() must be of the type string or null, float given, called in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Import.php on line 896 and defined in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Import.php:809 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Import.php(896): PhpMyAdmin\Import->detectType(0, 140,35435673674) #1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\Import\ImportOds.php(358): PhpMyAdmin\Import->analyzeTable(Array) #2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\import.php(572): PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Import\ImportOds->doImport(Array) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Import.php on line 809.

Agradezco su colaboracion. Tengan un buen dia.

Comment: hola como estas me gustaria saber si pudiste solucionar tu problema por q me pasa lo mismo y nose que hacer?